# update twitter status from your own website?

Tags: twitter

I need some kind of Twitter feed functionality that allows people to post/reply to tweets from the website and not from the Twitter site. Is this possible? If so, what would be the best way to go about this? Does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter offers [@Anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin), and that sounds like what you are looking for. Essentially, this product lets you integrate Twitter features into your site using snippets of javascript. Of particular interest to you may be the [TweetBox](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#tweetbox).

Additionally, [jTweetsAnywhere](http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/), a jQuery Twitter widget, supports @Anywhere functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Wordpress ,take a look at [Tweeter Tools plugin](http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/plugins/twitter-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Drupal you can take a look at the twitter module or twitter @anywhere module.