# Post to social media whilst posting on website

Tags: php, html, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I need to create a website that acts as a blog, but I want every update/post that I put up to also be posted to Facebook and Twitter immediately.
Is there an API that I can use for this?
I am new to this and am not sure of where to begin.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

[This post has what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132630/how-do-i-update-facebook-status-from-my-own-website), a full rundown of the Facebook SDK and how to integrate it. It's actually quite straightforward (I've used it a few times for clients who wanted heavy social media integration). You basically need to develop an app to integrate with the Facebook SDK. Twitter is similar. [This thread should point you in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766332/update-twitter-status-from-your-own-website)